# Alternative UI design to provide access to multiple users

Tags: user-behavior, interface, webforms

[image]Problem: Part of the application has access to only specific users. Eg View only, Add item, and edit. Only admin can give access.

I have already tried toggle buttons and check boxes. Wondering if there any other better way to implement it.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is it about giving access or about displaying UI differently depending on the user?

Comment: Added above picture for reference, Its about displaying UI for giving access.  Only admin can give access. And also Tried Check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to have 2 permission types:

1. View
2. Edit - includes "Add", "update", and "delete"

Is that something you can do or a user can have a single permission only?

Here are two solutions to think about:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach is that you use Access Templates. Meaning that for each part of your application you can set None, View or Full access in the Access Template. Then you add an Access Template to each user instead. Gives a fine grain control and unlimited configuration settings over access in you application